# How do I evaluate this sum :$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n-1}\log n}{n^s}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, zeta-functions

How do I evaluate this sum :$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n-1}\log n}{n^s}$$

**Note** : In wolfram alpha it is convergent for $Re(s)>1$ .!!

Thank you for any help

Comment: u may write this as the derivative of a Hurwitz eta function which can be reudced to usal zeta function and their derivative.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @tired's comment, your sum is

$$
\zeta'(s)\left(2^{1-s}-1\right)-\zeta(s)2^{1-s}\ln2
$$

Though if you simply want to compute it numerically, you may also consider the conceptually simpler act of computing successive partial sums until convergence up to a desired error tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that we have the Dirichlet eta function:

$$\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}$$

And its derivative:

$$\eta'(s)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\ln(n)}{n^s}$$